# What are all the NHibernate HiLo generator params?

Tags: nhibernate, hilo

I've seen some docs by Fabio Maulo that shows the following params:

```
<id name="Id" type="Int64" column="cat_id">
    <generator class="hilo">
            <param name="table">hi_value</param>
            <param name="column">next_value</param>
            <param name="max_lo">100</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

However, on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023917) the poster uses a `<param name="schema">...` I'd like to be able to specify schema for the HiLo generator.

Is there definitive documentation for all generator parameters? I've tried googling it without success.

Answer (score 2):

Another param to throw in the mix is

```
<param name="where">TableName='CmsLogin'</param>
```

This gives you the ability to have different counters per entity rather than a counter for all entities.

However I have not seen a way to specify the schema as a param so I think you need to go with creating a separate HiLo Key table for each unique schema in the database.

Comment: Thanks Rippo, I used that option initially before I realised I could just use a different column for each table.

Comment: @MikeScott any chance you can post an example?

Comment: @Ufuk, do you mean an example of using different columns in the hilo table for each table that uses a hilo generator? If so, I think that would be better as a different question as it's not really on topic. Post a question and I'll be happy to answer with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source, the full list is: "table", "column", "max_lo", "schema", "catalog" and "where", but I don't know if they are all being used.
These are defined in classes NHibernate.Id.TableGenerator and NHibernate.Id.TableHiLoGenerator .