# Are HiLo IDs unique across different tables?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two different classes that map to two different database tables. IDs are created by NHibernate using the HiLo generator:

```
<generator class="hilo">
    <param name="table">uid</param>
    <param name="column">column</param>
</generator>
```

Are the IDs unique across both tables if I use the same `table` and `column` parameters for both mappings? If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate will distribute unique ids among all these tables, which use the same setting *(table and column)*

If we want to have different id rows/sets, we can use another param:

```
<param name="where">TableName='CmsLogin'</param>
```

see more here:

#### [What are all the NHibernate HiLo generator params?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3942870/1679310)